# Deploy to AppStore fails since I added a watchOS project (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: ios, xamarin, deployment, xamarin.ios, publish

Since I added a watchOS project I'am not able to deploy my app to the AppStore anymore. I got this message:

> ERROR ITMS-90034: "Missing or invalid signature. The bundle
>   'com.SoftwareNotion.LottoStats.watchkitapp.watchkitextension' at
>   bundle path
>   'Payload/LottoStats.iOS.app/Watch/LottoStatsiOSLottoStatsWatch.app/PlugIns/LottoStatsiOSLottoStatsWatchExtension.appex'
>   is not signed using an Apple submission certificate."

I double checked my settings and can't find a mistake. I'm using the latest Xamarin Studio stable build for my Mac OS to deploy. Did I need to set the watchOS (and it's extension) project to Configuration "AppStore" too? Because there is only "Debug" and "Release" available. I use this guide for my configuration: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/deployment/appstore/

---

Just made a validation check with XCode for the Archive. And it looks like the certificate is not injected for the watchOS projects. How can I configure Xamarin Studio for this process?

watchOS porject bundle config: http://puu.sh/tSize/c2c5e927ae.jpg 
watchOS EX project bundle config: http://puu.sh/tSiA1/dbbc939e96.jpg

XCode package validation: http://puu.sh/tSjcI/3434b431f3.jpg

---

Hope someone can help because I want to deploy for a TestFlight test since last friday now and this stuff makes me sick, that I don't get it why it wont work as expected...

---

I solved the problem by recreating the certificates. But now I have the problem that Xamarin tells me that the app has 64MB and only 50MB are allowed (the actual WatchOS App is 11,4MB)?!

Comment: Which linker option are you using in your Project Properties/Options -> iOS Build settings for the configuration you are using?  If using "Don't Link" (or "None" depending in the IDE you are using) then try the "Link SDK assemblies only" (in Xamarin Studio, in Visual Studio I believe the option is called "Link Framework SDKs only") See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/